# Triangulation of 6 points from 4 views

Tags: computer-vision, opencv3.0, triangulation, vision

I have 4 different views of an object, each with its corresponding K and M camera matrices (intrinsic and extrinsic parameters).

I have 6 3D points which i marked on each of the 2D views (so 24 2d points).

What i am trying to do to back-project those 2D points to 3D and get my 6 3D points in space.

Most papers show how to do it when you have 2 views and their matrices.
However, I have 4 views. I am using OpenCV in Python.

As a first approach maybe i could triangulate using all combinations of 2 views, so i get 4choose2 = 6 sets of 3D points and then I average over all triangulations.

Is there a better approach that would be more advisable?
Do you think i should use something other than OpenCV? (it still has to be Python though)

Comment: OpenCV's `cvTriangulatePoints()` supports only **two-view** triangulation. Major bummer **:|**      I've added a [feature request](http://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13077)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two solutions for your problem.

**1. Analytic Solution**

If you do the math, you find that each 2D to 3D correspondence adds 2 equations to the triangulation system. With 6 views you will then get a system with 12 equations and 3 unknowns. This should be the most efficient implementation, but could be unstable when noisy inputs are expected.

**2. Triangulate + Optimize**

Compute an estimated 3D point with classic 2-View triangulation. Use non-linear optimization to compute the 3D point that minimized the reprojection error to all 6 views. This is my recommend solution, because it should be stable and everything is already implemented in OpenCV.

Comment: For the second method, would you be referring to this function by any chance? https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#correctmatches

Comment: No, you can use that, but it is not enough. You need an optimization over multiple cameras and points. The keyword here is Bundle Adjustment.

Comment: I am given the projection matrices and corresponding points, i think this is more appropriate https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d0/dbd/group__triangulation.html#ga211c855276b3084f3bbd8b2d9161dc74

Comment: That method is the first solution of my answer. You can try that, should be a good starting point.